# How can I change the colour of selected text in a WPF ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application, I have defined the following style for TextBlocks.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.40"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The style is intentionally defined at the highest level of my application so that it applies to all TextBlocks by default.

The problem is that this style breaks the behaviour of TextBlocks in ComboBoxes. Normally, the selected item in a ComboBox has its Foreground colour change to white. With this style applied however, the foreground colour of the text does not change.

How can I trigger the text to change colour when the TextBlock in a ComboBox is highlighted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by moving the styles out of `app.xaml` and into a separate resource dictionary that I include as needed in my application Window & Pages.

This stops the `TextBlock` style from affecting the colour of the text in the `ComboBox`. Finally, to achieve the text colour I wanted on all items I overrode the following default system colours with my own.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}"
                 Color="{StaticResource TextColor}"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}"
                 Color="{StaticResource TextColor}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to change the texblock foreground for selected item(say Red), just add this to your style resources:

```
<Style.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
</Style.Resources>
```

Comment: I tried using this as an alternative solution to my general problem which is that I want all text in my application to (by default) be a particular colour and size.

It almost worked, but I couldn't find a system brush that controlled the colour of freestanding TextBlocks. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can have a look at this in case if you want other brush here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx?ppud=4

Comment: Right. I commented out the style when I was experimenting with this. I did set a value for SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey, but this did not change the colour of text in a TextBlock ... I was surprised by this.

Comment: This ended up being helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add second style based on your first and reset background property.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextBrush}"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" x:Key="ResetBG">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Control.Background}"/>
</Style>

<TextBlock Text="Red"/>
<TextBlock Text="Default" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ResetBG}"/>
```

Comment: The TextBlocks occur inside of ComboBox, they are not explicitly declared anywhere in my markup.