# Presenting readonly data in a wpf form

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am searching for the "right" way of styling a textbox for showing read-only data.
Normal if you set a textbox to read-only the text somehow become dimed. What I would like is this

- See that the data is read-only
- Easily read the text
- Be able to copy the text
- Should be able to see the control if there is no data.

I could give the background or border another color but maybe I am missing out of something? is there a skilled designer out there (-:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996262/how-can-i-change-the-colour-of-selected-text-in-a-wpf-combobox

Answer (score 0):

For solve this problem you should use RichTextBox inside TextBlock.

Here is my sample of code read-only TextBlock with scrollbar, auto-wrapping and possibility to copy text >

```
<DockPanel>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBlock IsEnabled="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
           <RichTextBox Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" IsDocumentEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </TextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```